# GraphQL-codegen fails to load GraphQLSchema

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

So i have a problem loading a GraphQl schema using gql-codegen. When I try to generate, it fails with 404 error, however schema is available at http://localhost:8000/graphql below is the error.
[image]

```
 Cannot convert undefined or null to object
      TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
      at Function.entries (<anonymous>)
```

I've tried to replace `locahost` with `127.0.0.1` in my npm file but i got the same result.
Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some debugging I found that the error comes from `../node_modules/@graphql-tools/url-loader/cjs/index.js` from the following method:

```
  class UrlLoader {
       ...
   handleSDL(pointer, fetch, options) {
       for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(options.headers)) {
                    if (key.startsWith(':')) {
                      // omit http2 headers
                      isHttp2 = true;
                    } else {
                      headers[key] = value
                    }
                  }   
        return new value_or_promise_1.ValueOrPromise(() => fetch(pointer, {
                method: defaultMethod,
                headers: typeof (options === null || options === void 0 ? void 0 : options.headers) === 'function' ? options.headers() : options === null || options === void 0 ? void 0 : options.headers,
            }))
    ... }
```

The problem was that the options.headers property might be undefined or null, which cannot be iterated using Object.entries(). What solved my problem was adding a check to ensure that `options.headers` is defined before iterating through its entries:

```
if (options.headers) {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(options.headers)) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

And similarly, for the fetch call, I added a check to ensure that `options.headers` is defined before passing it to the fetch method.:

```
return new value_or_promise_1.ValueOrPromise(() => fetch(pointer, {
  method: defaultMethod,
  headers: typeof options?.headers === 'function' ? options.headers() : options?.headers || {},
}));
```

Then after running `gql-gen` again the error was gone and everything worked as expected.